Are the Y and H transforms inverses of each other for any $\nu$?
In my work I have come across a function which is defined on the whole real axis and diverges at the origin. I would like to expand it in terms of spherical Bessel funcions of the second kind. I have recently come across the Wikipedia page on the Y and H transforms (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y_and_H_transforms), which are defined as
\begin{align}
F(k) &= \int_0^\infty f(r) Y_\nu(kr) \sqrt{kr} \, dr \hspace{3cm} \text{(Y transform)}  \\
f(r) &= \int_0^\infty F(k) \mathbf{H}_\nu(kr) \sqrt{kr} \, dk  \hspace{3cm} ( \mathbf{H}\text{ transform)},
\end{align}
where $Y_{\nu}$ and $\mathbf{H}_\nu$ are the Bessel functions of the second kind and the Struve functions, respectively. It is stated (and implied by the above equations) that these two transforms are inverses of each other. However, in the Tables of Integral Transforms (Bateman Manuscript Project), which is cited in the Wikipedia page, it is only stated that these two are inverses of each other for
\begin{equation}
- \frac{1}{2} < \text{Re} \, \nu < \frac{1}{2}.
\end{equation}
I am interested in $\nu=1/2+l$ with $l$ a positive integer, since this is the case that corresponds to the spherical functions. Are the Y and $\mathbf{H}$ transforms still the inverses of each other in this case? If not, does there exist an appropriate inverse of the Y transform for $\nu = 1/2+l$?
